# Bibliography not compiling 10

Tags: bibtex, errors

Does anyone solve the following problem, finally? Beforehand thank you!

#### `Thesis_Final_ps_11142012a.blg`

> ```
> This is BibTeX, Version 0.99c (TeX Live 2009/Debian)
> The top-level auxiliary file: Thesis_Final_ps_11142012a.aux
> A level-1 auxiliary file: Applications.aux
> A level-1 auxiliary file: LiteratureReview.aux
> A level-1 auxiliary file: Microgravity.aux
> A level-1 auxiliary file: modified-evolution-equation-11_08_2012.aux
> A level-1 auxiliary file: ConstitutiveRelationship_05_17_2012a.aux
> A level-1 auxiliary file: MaximizingWavenumber_11082012.aux
> A level-1 auxiliary file: Validation_ps.aux
> A level-1 auxiliary file: Results_1.aux
> A level-1 auxiliary file: Contributions.aux
> A level-1 auxiliary file: mathfluid_3.aux
> I found no \bibdata command---while reading file Thesis.aux
> I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file Thesis.aux
> (There were 2 error messages)
> ```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE . Did you use `\bibdata` or `\bibstyle` command in your file? It's the two errors shown by bibtex

Comment: did you call \bibliographystlye before \bibliograpy?

Comment: Can you please show a minimal `.tex` manuscript that you are using which creates the error in your post?

Comment: My guess is that your tex file is lacking a `\bibliographystyle` statement. However, that's just a guess at this point, as you haven't provided the code that gives rise to the problem(s) you're encountering.

Comment: It is rather curious that the top of the blg says `Thesis_Final_ps_11142012a.aux` but that  the complain is about `Thesis.aux`. I wonder how you managed to get this output.

Answer (score 1):

The log file given above shows that:

```
I found no \bibdata command
```

which means, you have not loaded bib database file in `\bibliography{}` command.

Likewise,

```
I found no \bibstyle command
```

means, you have not given the bibliography style in `\bibliographystyle{}`.